# CRSF token for non-text inputs or textarea forms php

Tags: php, forms, session, csrf

I'm implementing CSRF tokens to my forms of my website and I have this form

```
 <form method=post action="">
  <input type=hidden name=id_follower value=1 />
  <input type=hidden name=id_followed value=3 />
    <input type=hidden name=follow value=yes />
              <input type=submit value=Follow />
  </form>
```

Where if I click on the button then me (user 1) follow user 3 (processed via ajax). Do I need a CSRF token for this form? bearing in mind I have no `type=['text']` input or `textarea`?

Comment: Those inputs won't work.

Comment: what do you mean by saying that they wont work

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html and compare those with yours.

Comment: I know they are not sintactically correct, but what I want is to know if needed to implement CSFR token.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you must have CSRF token to avoid security problems.
For example, any website owner can create own hidden Ajax request to your site to make your user follow another one :)